# Is there a way to see if a specific field exists in any of the tables in a database?

Tags: sql-server, database, field

I have a SQL Server database which contains ~100 tables, each consisting of between 50-450 columns (fields), and I want to know if a certain field exists in any of the tables without having to check them all manually.

For example, I want to find out which tables contain the field `household_no`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: 450 columns in a single table is a design smell, even 50 columns is a bit strange. I suspect poor normalization

Comment: I was waiting for that comment and I completely agree.  Not surprisingly, the person who created it is no longer with the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use the `sys` objects:

```sql
SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,
       t.[name] AS TableName
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.[name] = N'household_no';
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Would this allow me to effectively search through all ~100 tables for `household_no`? Comments would be helpful.

Comment: Because it's referencing `sys.tables` ,@Mus ; a system table with the details of all the tables in your database.

Comment: Oh right, I never knew that. Thank you.

Comment: In all honesty I'm not sure what comments this one needs, @Mus . The objects are *literally* named with what they contain: `schemas` contains the schemas, `tables`, contains the tables, `columns`, contains the columns. Unsurprising, the column `name` (which all 3 tables have), is the *name* of the object. Which of those confuse you and I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: It's all good, I've got it now. Thanks.

Comment: I also wonder, could this be extended to work across a number of different databases/marts (with the same connection details), too?

Comment: You would need to use a dynamic statement to do that, @Mus .